Firebase Remote Config - Param's conditions is not working properly
In my firebase project i have remote config params and i´m getting these params from my flutter app, but the conditions is not working properly, this is the param that is not working:
param
and the conditios is the following:
condition code
and the code that i´m using is the following:
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  await requestPermision();
  await instance.ensureInitialized();
  await instance.setConfigSettings(
    RemoteConfigSettings(
      fetchTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 4),
      minimumFetchInterval: Duration.zero,
    ),
  );
  await instance.setDefaults(const {
    "counter_title": "title",
    "update": "1.0.2"
  });
  await instance.fetchAndActivate();


and i´m calling the param like this:
final json = instance.getString("update");
print("data obtained in app version: $json");


but i´m getting 1.0.0 that is the remote config console default value, i´m using this implementation from two android devices, a google pixel 5 and a kalley blackz,
what could be happening?
